Admonitions not rendering in Redocly
We're using Redocly to document our API.
The Warning admonition markdown we embed into our openapi.yaml file is not rendering correctly. According to the documentation the following markdown should render a warning admonition:
:::warning

I told you so!

:::

That admonition should look like this:

Instead, we're getting the following output when running npx @redocly/cli@latest preview-docs openapi.yaml

I've tried adding additional spaces between the opening and closing :::, as well as above and below the opening and closing tags. Nothing has worked.
Below is some information about our environment:
$ npx node -v
v16.13.2

$ npx @redocly/cli@latest --version
1.16.0


where are you using this syntax?

Within markdown defined under info > description

Any feedback, please?
